# Setting Firebase Database Url causes halt

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have updated Unity from 2019 to 2020 LTS and at the same time Firebase SDK to 10.3 from 8.10. Now I have an issue with the following lines:

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Options.DatabaseUrl = new Uri ("https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com/");
reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

Anything after either of these lines does not execute on the Android build. There was no issue before the update, and this is an app that has been using Firebase Realtime Database with no issues until now. Also weirdly there is no such issue on Unity Editor. The lines are executed there.

I don't see any crash on Android Logcat or Crashlytics. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by doing a new clean install of firebase. I was able to remove it completely via external dependancy manager -> version handler.